# Find cells within a range if one cell equals a criteria copy its value to another column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having real trouble trying to get this to work for me. To help explain what I need to do I've produced a (hopefully) very simple example below...

What I would like to do is:

- Within a range of cells `A:A` find `J Bloggs` (note there can be multiple entries and I need all of them)
- When an order from `J Blogs` is found copy his order date `B1`, request del. date `C1` and actual del. date `D1`
- Paste this information into a table `G1:J4`

NB: The list of customers can be long, and some customers may make seperate orders. I need to generate a list of all of these orders (don't need to check if date is in the past etc.).

Each time the query is run, say this time for `H Simpson`, only the details for `H Simpson` will appear in the table `G1:J4`

```
+---------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+  
|   Customer    |   Order Date   | Requested Delivery  | Actual Delivery  |  
+---------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+  
| J Bloggs      | 01/01/2013     |  02/01/2013         |  02/01/2013      |  
| H Simpson     | 05/01/2013     |  08/01/2013         |  09/01/2013      |  
| A Name        | 10/01/2013     |  10/01/2013         |  10/01/2013      |   
| J Bloggs      | 15/01/2013     |  22/01/2013         |  22/01/2013      |  
+---------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Y dont you try Pivot table---linked witih G1:J4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lucky day! I had a free spare minutes and wrote this code for you.

It will ask you for the `Name` - you simply select the cell with the name you wan't to generate data for

It will create a *table* in columns `G:J` and stick in the results of matches in columns `A:D`

```
Sub Findining()

    Dim r As Range, i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range
    Range("G:J").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To 4
        Cells(1, i + 6) = Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Name", Type:=8)
    If r.Columns.Count > 1 Or r.Rows.Count > 1 Then
      Do Until (r.Columns.Count = 1 And r.Rows.Count = 1)
        MsgBox "You can only select 1 name"
        Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Name", Type:=8)
      Loop
    End If

    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range("A" & i)
        If StrComp(r, rng, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            For j = 0 To 3
                Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Offset(0, 6 + j).Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1, rng.Offset(0, 6 + j).Column).Value = rng.Offset(0, j).Value
            Next j
        End If
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i
    Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: it's people like you that make this forum what it is :) Thank you!

Comment: @hs0 enjoy and thanks. and please do not call this site a *forum* :) it's a Q&A site not a forum :)

Comment: something that I've noticed with the code you provided is that if a date is missing, the entire contents of that collumn is moved up one cell to fill the missing value. This means rows further down the table become out of alignment. Do you know why?

Comment: yes i do. because the code copies offsets and not entire rows. That said it doesn't take all four rows at the same time and copies them over one by one. So if a value i missing anywhere in between columns A:D then the resulting set will not be accurate. If date is missing all other below cells will be shifted up by the amount of empty rows. You can add a function that checks current row and returns true or false, or add error handling to the code with a popup saying there is an empty cell. Or just simply make sure there are no empty rows in columns A:D using `=COUNTBLANK(range)`

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three different approaches:

1. Use AutoFilter
2. Use a macro to extract the data
3. Use VLOOKUP()

Using VLOOKUP() to get more than one result is explained here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I go with Vasim every time, eg:

[image: SO18655770 example]